# Can't install urllib2 for python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, urllib2

I try to install module urllib2 for python 2.7 (I as usual use command pip install), but have an error

No matching distribution found for urllib2..

What should I do?

Comment: Isn't `urllib2` an already existing standard library with the python installation? Open a python instance and try importing first.

Comment: What error does that throw?

Answer (score 36):

You don't need to pip install urllib/urllib2

In **Python 2.7** , urllib and urllib2 comes with python .

```
import urllib
```

OR

```
import urllib2
```

In **Python 3+** , urllib2 is replaced with urllib.request.

```
 import urllib.request  as urllib2
```